# Gatsby Wordpress use createTypes in GraphQL schema for missing ACF fields

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am using gatsby-source-wordpress. If i have a ACF repeater field, within that another field, like Link for instance I get an error if any post has an empty field - eg:
"- Unknown field 'partners' on type 'wordpress__POSTAcf'."

my graphQL looks like the following

```
{
 allWordpressPost {
   edges {
     node {
       title
       acf {
         project_students
         partners {
           partner_link {
             title
             url
             target
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

}

I've been trying to follow this for ACF fields to at least get an empty or null on the field which i can handle in the JS, right now Gatsby wont build. heres the Gatsby documentation which I don't quite understand for wordpress:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-04-new-schema-customization/
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createTypes

I have tried the following in gatsby-node.js which isn't working so far!

```
// using Gatsby Type Builder API
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, schema }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;
  const typeDefs = [
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: "wordpressPost",
      acf: {
        partners: {
          partner_link: {
            title: "String!",
            url: "String!",
            target: "String!",
          }
        }
      },
      interfaces: ["Node"],
      extensions: {
        infer: false
      }
    })
  ];
  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

Comment: Right there with you. The docs leave a lot to guess work, which is very very expensive in our fields. Did you ever figure this out without some hack? Right now I am doing the hack where I populate the first row with dummy content for graphql to infer from then I skip the first row when I iterate it on the front end... very ugly, but works. I would prefer the schema definitions to work and like you, I cannot get this to work since their docs dont explain how to connect the definition to the schema type.

Comment: i've not got very far with creating the schema as i was trying to do above. In the most recent version of Gatsby i noticed theres info in the CLI that suggests a schema. However i've also been trying to get wordpress to create null fields correctly. As far as i'm aware you need to add code to your functions.php or plugin as suggested in the gatsby-wordpress-source page AND create a bit of dummy content to prevent errors. I've recently commented here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13931 about this. Still looking for a decent solution

Comment: Yeah, I have nullified fields as well and that works for the most part. But I have a group of relations that can take one post type or another and there is a set of fields between the two that only one has, which causes an unknown field issue. Unfortunately, none of the docs cover cases like this and I havent been able to get createSchemaCustomization to cooperate. I'll let you know if I find a way that doesn't violate my own personal code standard